# Posting check box values in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to POST a form in rails that has multiple checkbox in it but i am running into trouble since the last few days.Below is the form that has the checkbox

```
    <%=form_tag (diffreport_path) do |f|%>
    <div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="Diff_table">
                <thead>
                    <th>File name</th>
                    <th>Download link</th>
                    <th>Select</th>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% @files.each do |file|%>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= file.name%></td>
                        <td><%= link_to "Download_file", file.attachment_url%></td>
                        <td><%= check_box_tag "file_ids[]", file.id %> </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>        
        </table>
        <br>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" id="diff_report_div">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="clear_selection">Clear Selection</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <%= submit_tag "Create a Diff report",class: "btn btn-primary"%>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

When i check a single box i can pass params hash

```
   {"utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"cY1ugfVkbkg3gILiJEtJo5L5LaQjG9R2jj5RRTe11n4=",
    "file_ids"=>["9"],
    "commit"=>"Create a Diff report"
    }
```

But when i check multiple check box .I dont see any value being passed in the params hash.

```
   {"utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"cY1ugfVkbkg3gILiJEtJo5L5LaQjG9R2jj5RRTe11n4=",
    "commit"=>"Create a Diff report"
    }
```

When i inspect the HTML source code. It does seem fine but may i am missing something. Below the HTML code rendered.I am not sure why this is happening.

```
   <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/diffreport" method="post">
    <div style="display:none">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />    
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="cY1ugfVkbkg3gILiJEtJo5L5LaQjG9R2jj5RRTe11n4=" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="Diff_table">
    <thead>
    <th>File name</th>
    <th>Download link</th>
    <th>Select</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>RDK_v8</td>
    <td>
    <a  href="/uploads/data_model_file/attachment/9/RDKVB_DataModel_v2.9.xlsm">
    Download_fi  le</a>
    </td>
    <td><input checked="checked" id="file_names_" name="file_names[]"   type=   "checkbox" value="9" /> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>RDK_v10</td>
    <td><a   href="/uploads/data_model_file/attachment/10/RDKVB_DataModel_v2.9.xlsm">Download_f ile</a></td>
    <td><input checked="checked" id="file_names_" name="file_names[]"   type="checkbox" value="10" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>RDK_v11</td>
    <td><a   href="/uploads/data_model_file/attachment/11/RDKVB_DataModel_v2.9.xlsm">Download_file</a>
    </td>
    <td><input checked="checked" id="file_names_" name="file_names[]"   type="checkbox" value="11" /> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>RDK_v12</td>
    <td><a   href="/uploads/data_model_file/attachment/12/RDKVB_DataModel_v2.9.xlsm">Download_f ile</a>
    </td>
    <td><input checked="checked" id="file_names_" name="file_names[]"  type="checkbox" value="12" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>RDK_v13</td>
    <td><a  href="/uploads/data_model_file/attachment/13/RDKVB_DataModel_v2.9.xlsm">Download_file</a>
    </td>
    <td><input checked="checked" id="file_names_" name="file_names[]"  type="checkbox" value="13" />
   </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
  <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" id="diff_report_div">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="clear_selection">Clear Selection</button>
  <br>
  <br>
   <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create a Diff  report" />
  </div>
  </form>
```

So i just need why i am not able to pass more than one value in the array when i check more than one checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is "html doesn't quite work that way".

This line of ruby code here:

```
<%= check_box_tag "file_ids[]", file.id %>
```

builds all of the check boxes right?
Have you noticed in the html that what it builds looks like this:

```
<input checked="checked" id="file_names_" 
<input checked="checked" id="file_names_" 
<input checked="checked" id="file_names_"
```

ie every single checkbox has the same id: `file_names_`
How does the browser tell which checkboxes have been checked?

HTML requires that every field has a *unique* id. eg the html should have something like:

```
<input checked="checked" id="file_names_1" 
<input checked="checked" id="file_names_2" 
<input checked="checked" id="file_names_2"
```

Then the browser can tell you that `file_names_1` and `file_names_3` have been checked, but not `file_names_2`

To do that in rails, you need to pass something unique (in this case the file.id) into the *name* of the checkbox (not just the value) eg:

```
<%= check_box_tag "file_ids[#{file.id}]", file.id %>
```

Give that a shot and see whether it helps.

Note: yes I know lots of old rails examples don't require that... things have changed a bit.

Comment: I just tried it  and it didnt work .With a single check box check the hash looks like this {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"cY1ugfVkbkg3gILiJEtJo5L5LaQjG9R2jj5RRTe11n4=", "file_ids"=>{"9"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Create a Diff report"}. But for multiple check box checked again  there is no attribute for file file_id in the params hash                                                 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"cY1ugfVkbkg3gILiJEtJo5L5LaQjG9R2jj5RRTe11n4=", "commit"=>"Create a Diff report"} even though the check box had unique ids.